# Styling Sold Out Options in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to add css to product options to provide the user with a visual indication of which options are not available (sold out). This works when a product only has one set of option values, however my product has two ("date", and "time"). I have this working most of the way, however the available "Time" options are not updated when I switch between dates. Any help here would be hugely appreciated.

Inside my product-form.liquid file I have the following code to add a class to sold out options. Perhaps I need some js?

In case it's helpful, I'm using the Prestige theme and the page is here: https://neetfield.co.uk/pizza

```
                {%- if option.name == "Time" and product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 == product.variants[forloop.index0].option1 -%}
                  {%- if product.variants[forloop.index0].available -%}
                    {%- assign opt_sold = false -%}
                  {%- else -%}
                    {%- assign opt_sold = true -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
                {%- else -%}
                  {%- assign opt_sold = false -%}
                {%- endif -%}
```

And then this is used to add a class to sold out options `{% if opt_sold %}opt-sold-out{% endif %}`

This is a screenshot of where I got to (now disabled on the live site until I haved it working when switching between dates):

[image]

Comment: Hi! did you try to add an attribute in product variants?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help as I think I need to refresh the "time" options every time the "Date" option is updated by the user. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: For example I'm using this in Product swatch or button option    {%- if product.inventory_quantity > 0 -%}qty_add="avl" {%else%}qty_add="sold"{%-endif-%}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First page render (Liquid)

For the initial page load you can use something like this:

```
{%- liquid
  assign selected_option_1 = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1
  assign relevant_variants = product.variants | where: 'option1', selected_option_1
  assign available_timeslots = ''

  for variant in relevant_variants
    if variant.available
      assign available_timeslots = available_timeslots | append: ',' | append: variant.option2
    endif
  endfor

  assign available_timeslots = available_timeslots | remove_first: ',' | split: ','
-%}
```

This snippet iterates over all product variants where `option1` equals the `option1` value of the currently selected variant (e.g. "Saturday 4th June"). For each variant we'll check if its available and push it to the `available_timeslots` array.

Make sure to place this snippet before iterating over all product options.

Finally, use this array to check if an option value is available:

```
{%- unless available_timeslots contains value -%}
  Disable option input
{%- endunless -%}
```

`value` basically is a value of `option.values`. I'm sure you'll find this somewhere in your product-form :)

## After user interaction (JavaScript)

Since Liquid is a server-side rendered template language, you can only achieve this by updating the option input elements on variant change via JavaScript on the client-side. The Shopify Prestige theme has a useful [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) for this scenario: `variant:changed`

An example of the implementation would look like this:

```js
/**
 * Gets the option index that is different between `variant` in `previousVariant`.
 *
 * @param {object} variant
 * @param {object} previousVariant
 * @returns {1 | 2 | 3}
 */
const getChangedOptionIndex = (variant, previousVariant) => {
  let changedOptionIndex;

  for (let i = 0; i < variant.options.length; i++) {
    if (variant.options[i] !== previousVariant.options[i]) {
      changedOptionIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return changedOptionIndex;
};

/**
 * Find a variant via its options.
 *
 * @param {object[]} variants
 * @param {{ option1: string, option2: string }} options
 * @returns {object | undefined}
 */
const findVariantByOptions = (variants, { option1, option2 }) => {
  return variants.find((variant) => variant.option1 === option1 && variant.option2 === option2);
};

const { product } = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('script[data-product-json]').innerHTML);

document.addEventListener('variant:changed', (event) => {
  // We might need a sanity check here. For example, if the current variant is
  // "Saturday 4th June / 18:30" and you switch to "Saturday 11th June" the time option
  // "18:30" might not exist which would result in `event.detail` being `undefined`.
  // if (!event.detail.variant) {
  //
  // }

  const { variant, previousVariant } = event.detail;
  const changedOptionIndex = getChangedOptionIndex(variant, previousVariant);

  const optionInputEls = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="option-"]');

  // Note: This approach won't work anymore if a product has 3 options
  optionInputEls.forEach((optionInputEl) => {
    const optionIndex = Number(optionInputEl.name.split('-')[1]);

    // Only check option inputs that are not of the same group as the changed option
    if (optionIndex !== changedOptionIndex) {
      const foundVariant = findVariantByOptions(product.variants, {
        [`option${changedOptionIndex + 1}`]: variant.options[changedOptionIndex],
        [`option${optionIndex + 1}`]: optionInputEl.value,
      });

      if (!foundVariant || !foundVariant.available) {
        optionInputEl.nextElementSibling.classList.add('opt-sold-out');
      } else {
        optionInputEl.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('opt-sold-out');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Keep in mind that you are not really disabling the input. It's just visually indicating that it's disabled. If that's not a problem for you, just ignore this comment.

Note that this does not handle the following scenario:

- User chooses date "A"
- User chooses time "X"
- User chooses date "B" (where time "X" is not available)

I'm guessing that the decision which date to chose always comes first so this should not be an important scenario to worry about.

Comment: Dear lord that is helpful - thank you very much for taking the time. However there is one slight glitch... is there any way to make it fire on page load as well as on ```variant:changed```?

I have implemented this on the site (https://neetfield.co.uk/pizza) but as you can see, it's 99% of the way towards the perfect user experience.

Comment: @user2608266 you‘re welcome! Best practice would be to not rely on JavaScript before user interaction. So we‘d need to tackle this server-side via Liquid. I‘m guessing that it‘s not likely that the order of product options will change anytime soon, right? If so, I can help you with that last 1% :)

Comment: That is correct. The order of product options will remain the same 

Comment: I'm afraid this approach to the initial page load doesn't quite work. It looks like it might be hitting a time option that is out of stock and marking it as so for all variants that it belongs to? I might be wrong but all time variants are marked as unavailable on page load (the product is currently sold out of all "time" variants for the first "date" option - this may be helpful to know?)

Comment: @user2608266 could you please deploy the changes to a development theme and text me the preview link? Should be easier to debug the issue like this. In case you don't know: You can "build" a preview link by adding the `preview_theme_id` parameter to the URL with the actual theme ID as the value.

Comment: I'm sorry for the slow response! Here's the link: https://neetfield.co.uk/products/pizza?preview_theme_id=129379991706

Comment: @user2608266 well, it's exactly the other way around :D `{%- if available_timeslots contains value -%}Disable option input{%- endif -%}` should obviously be `{%- if available_timeslots contains value -%}Enable option input{%- endif -%}`. I have just updated my initial answer in regards to that issue :)

Comment: Oops! I can't believe I didn't notice that myself. Thank you very much indeed for all of your help! Everything is now working perfectly.

Comment: @user2608266 Glad that I could help. Let me know if any issues arise (e.g. dates not being displayed as sold out on page load; you'll probably face this issue soon). I would highly appreciate it if you can upvote and accept my answer. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @davidthorand Amazing solution. I wanted to implement this on a shop I am working on using Prestige theme and this works perfectly for products with multiple variant options. However, my shop has some products which only have one variant option, say in the case of the OP just the times without the date options. So when using this solution, variants for products with only the times option are all disabled since available_timeslots is empty. How do I need to edit the code in order to accomodate this use-case? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mysterio does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75675285/18794537) help? I'm not a 100% sure whether or not I understand your issue. Let me know if my answer did not help :D

Answer (score 1):

## Approach for products with a single option

This case is pretty easy and does not require any JavaScript since each option value maps to exactly one variant. The way to go here would be to get that variant and check if it's available:

```
{%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
  {%- for value in option.values -%}
    {%- assign variant = product.variants | where: 'option1', value -%}

    {%- if variant.available == false -%}
      Disable option input
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```